# Is there a Python equivalent to template literals in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, template-literals

To provide a basic example, say I wanted to write:

```
name = str(input())
age = int(input())
print('Hi, {name}, you are {age}.')
```

In javascript, this would look like:

```
console.log(`Hi, ${name}, you are ${age}.`)
```

I assume there is no direct implementation of template literals in Python, as I haven't found any mention on Google / DDG.

If I am correct in thinking that there isn't a direct implementation, have any of you found workarounds? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're after "format strings", see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting)

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I actually just now found this & was coming back to close this. 

Future readers - this example could be solved w/ print(f'Hi, {name}, you are {age}')

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can go with [**formatted string literals**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) ("f-strings") since Python 3.6

```py
f"Hi {name}, you are {age}"
```

Or string formatting

```
"Hi {}, you are {}".format(name, age)
"Hi {name}, you are {age}".format(name=name, age=age)
```

Or format specifiers

```
"Hi %s, you are %d" % (name, age)
```