# Getting an error as "decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, int found" while tried to return id and field value in django models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

**model #1**

```
class Add_Job(models.Model):
    
    job_name=models.CharField(max_length=254)
    client=models.ForeignKey(Client,on_delete=CASCADE,related_name='client')
    #client=models.ManyToManyField(Client)
    project=models.ForeignKey(Project,on_delete=CASCADE,related_name='project')
    #project=models.ManyToManyField(Project)
    user=models.ForeignKey(Users,on_delete=CASCADE)
    Hours=models.TimeField(null=True)
    start_Date = models.DateTimeField(max_length=10)
    end_Date=models.DateTimeField(max_length=10)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id, self.job_name)
```

**model #2**

```
class Add_Timelog(models.Model):
    
    
    project=models.ManyToManyField(Project)
    client=models.ManyToManyField(Client)
    Job=models.ManyToManyField(Add_Job)
    #Date = models.DateField(max_length=100 ,auto_now_add=True,editable=True)
    Date= models.DateField(default = datetime.date.today)
    Hours=models.TimeField(null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Date)
```

while I tried to return the 'id' and 'job_name' from the 'Add_Job' model it is getting reflected in the database table. But the 'Add_timelog' model is getting an error

> TypeError at /api/Add_Timelog/ decoding to str: need a bytes-like
> object, int found

Don't know why it is getting an error.

After update1:

```
class Add_Timelog(models.Model):
    
    
    project=models.ManyToManyField(Project)
    client=models.ManyToManyField(Client)
    Job=models.ManyToManyField(Add_Job)
    #Date = models.DateField(max_length=100 ,auto_now_add=True,editable=True)
    Date= models.DateField(default = datetime.date.today)
    Hours=models.TimeField(null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str( '{} {}'.format(self.Date, self.Hours))
```

**model 2**

```
class Consolidated(models.Model):
    
   emp_name=models.ManyToManyField(Users,related_name="employee_name+")
    proj_name=models.ManyToManyField(Project)
    custom_name=models.ManyToManyField(Client)
    Cons_date=models.ManyToManyField(Add_Timelog)
    bill_no_bill=models.ManyToManyField(Users,related_name="billable_and_non_billable+")
    hour_spent = models.ManyToManyField(Add_Timelog,related_name="hour_spent")
    
    def __str__(self):
       return str(self.emp_name)
```

So as per property method code it is returning the value as object and not as value. But I defined a str function and removed the property method and I am getting the value but both date and hours in the same field. But as per my model "consolidated", I need to get that date seperately and hours seperately. Is that possible to do that in django model ?

Comment: try to change your ``__str__`` return type like this ``return f"{self.Date}"``

Comment: I'm new to this django, can you please explain me in detail regarding the return 'f' type. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello @vinothkumar check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63678773/14457833) to get understanding about ``f""``

Comment: @ Ankit Tiwari I tried using this format function, but it doesn't work on the django rest framework. can you please suggest me other ways that could work on the django models.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like problem with Add_Job model, not Add_Timelog. In **str** method you are trying to convert id and job_name to str, but this raises TypeError. Try to change `return str(self.id, self.job_name)` to `return '{} {}'.format(str(self.id), self.job_name)` it's going to convert id of object to string and put it in first {} and job_name, which is already string in second {}

If you want to access both Date and Hours you can do it using `@property` method decorator. In your case you would need to write in your Add_Timelog model.

```
@property
def date_and_hours(self):
    return '{} {}'.format(self.Date, self.Hours)
```

If you want to get their values not string representation just return two values from property, but you need to unpack them.

```
@property
def date_and_hours(self):
    return self.Date, self.Hours
```

Comment: Thanks this works. But as a final output we need to return two fields value from the same model seperately( ex: from "Add_Timelog" model we need to return Date and Hours field seperately). Can this be done in django? Thanks in advance..

Comment: What do you mean by return fields seperately? Do you want their string representation or values?

Comment: I am trying to take the date and hours field as a input in another model and display the value on that model while I enter a value in date and hour field here.( Ex: if I enter a date as today and time as now in the Add_Timelog model, I need to get that value in another model  say "consolidated" as a seperate field using a foreign key). As of now iam only able to get the date to other model not the hours, but i need it both. kindly help on the same

Comment: Edited my answer to add some code there

Comment: I have updated my code after this solution as "after update1" can you please check and help to solve the issue. Thanks in advance